# Magento2: How to add custom section below the order total on the checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, onestepcheckout, order-summary

I want to add a custom section below the order total on the checkout page.

[image]

Comment: which section you want to add?

Comment: I want to add a custom discounted price in this section below the order total @RohanHapani